# Pegar Elemento selecionado da UL

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Preciso pegar o Nome apenas do Elemento que eu cliquei, mas quando eu procuro pelo `textContent` aparece todos os da `li`

```
<li class="folder folder-open Selected">
TesteNfseSPO
<ul>
    <li class="file">TesteNfseSPO.sln</li>
    <li class="folder">TesteNfseSPO
        <ul>
            <li class="file">TesteNfseSPO.csproj</li>
            <li class="file">Program.cs</li>
            <li class="file">app.config</li>
            <li class="folder">Properties
                <ul>
                    <li class="file">AssemblyInfo.cs</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="folder">bin
                <ul>
                    <li class="folder">Debug
                        <ul>
                            <li class="file">NfseSPO.dll</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="folder">obj
                <ul>
                    <li class="folder">Debug</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Eu gostaria por exemplo de quando eu clicar pegar apenas o "Program.cs" quando eu clico em cima dele, em todos os casos.

Comment: Você está usando algum framework javascript? ou só javascript puro?

Comment: Javascript Puro

Comment: Nesse caso o único jeito que me vem em mente (não é bonito), é criar uma função que receba o elemento clicado e no onclick chamar a função usando this: <li onclick="clicado(this)" ...

Comment: Atualiza a resposta com teu javascript que ficará mais fácil de te ajudar, André

Comment: Ainda não fiz o Javacript, mas esse código que eu mandei, vai ser gerado via uma DLL, então não posso colocar na tag o onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código abaixo está capturando todos os clicks realizados no documento, verificando se o elemento clicado é um `LI` e exibindo o textContent do seu primeiro elemento filho.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "LI") {
    alert(e.target.firstChild.textContent);
  }
});
```

```html
<li class="folder folder-open Selected">
  TesteNfseSPO
  <ul>
    <li class="file">TesteNfseSPO.sln</li>
    <li class="folder" id="teste">TesteNfseSPO
      <ul>
        <li class="file">TesteNfseSPO.csproj</li>
        <li class="file">Program.cs</li>
        <li class="file">app.config</li>
        <li class="folder">Properties
          <ul>
            <li class="file">AssemblyInfo.cs</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="folder">bin
          <ul>
            <li class="folder">Debug
              <ul>
                <li class="file">NfseSPO.dll</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="folder">obj
          <ul>
            <li class="folder">Debug</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, de forma simples e prática resolveu meu problema!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adaptar este código a sua necessidade.

```js
//Aqui pegamos todos os elementos que possui a classe '.file'
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.file');

//Depois no loop adicionamos o evento para cada elemento
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  items[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {    
    document.getElementById("ItemSelected").innerHTML = this.textContent;
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

```html
<li class="folder folder-open Selected">
TesteNfseSPO
<ul>
    <li class="file">TesteNfseSPO.sln</li>
    <li class="folder">TesteNfseSPO
        <ul>
            <li class="file">TesteNfseSPO.csproj</li>
            <li class="file">Program.cs</li>
            <li class="file">app.config</li>
            <li class="folder">Properties
                <ul>
                    <li class="file">AssemblyInfo.cs</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="folder">bin
                <ul>
                    <li class="folder">Debug
                        <ul>
                            <li class="file">NfseSPO.dll</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="folder">obj
                <ul>
                    <li class="folder">Debug</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="ItemSelected"></div>
```